# Visual Studio: Reload Dataset and Datagrid when there's structural change in Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to create an App with Visual Studio 2013 in .vb
This App works with a local database (books, Cd, Dvd, etc. that I have) made with Ms SQl SERVER EXPRESS, and I wonder if I can find a way to reload my DatagridView and my Dataset through the APP when I add a column to my database with the App. In fact I'm trying to find a way to show this new column in my datagridview and I don't want to go always in VS because I want use my App on a small laptop.

Well, I don't know where to start so I've tried this:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
...
Private Sub Form8_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-ME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM CONSULTE"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    cn.Open()
    adapter.Fill(ds, "CONSULTE")
    cn.Close()
    CONSULTEDataGridView.DataSource = ds
    CONSULTEDataGridView.DataMember = "CONSULTE"

End Sub
```

But It does'nt work.

My windows form where I can ALTER TABLE:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form7
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-ME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader

Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cmd.Connection = cn
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If table.Text <> "" And colonne.Text <> "" And typede.Text <> "" Then
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & table.Text & " ADD " & colonne.Text & " " & typede.Text & ""
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        table.Text = ""
        colonne.Text = ""
        typede.Text = ""
    Else
        MsgBox("Vous devez remplir les trois champs!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If table.Text <> "" And colonne.Text <> "" Then
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & table.Text & " DROP COLUMN " & colonne.Text & ""
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        table.Text = ""
        colonne.Text = ""
    Else
        MsgBox("Vous devez remplir correctement les deux premiers champs!")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for you help!

PS: Sorry for my English, it's not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a way! If somebody wants to know, here is an example:
Datagridview1 is the name of my datagridview on form1

Form 1:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-ME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BDD;Integrated Security=True")
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT * FROM CONSULTE"
    adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

End Sub
End Class
```

Form 3, where I can add or delete columns:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form3
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-ME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BDD;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cmd.Connection = cn
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If table.Text <> "" And colonne.Text <> "" And typede.Text <> "" Then
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & table.Text & " ADD " & colonne.Text & " " & typede.Text & ""
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        table.Text = ""
        colonne.Text = ""
        typede.Text = ""
    Else
        MsgBox("Vous devez remplir les trois champs!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If table.Text <> "" And colonne.Text <> "" Then
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & table.Text & " DROP COLUMN " & colonne.Text & ""
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        table.Text = ""
        colonne.Text = ""
    Else
        MsgBox("Vous devez remplir correctement les deux premiers champs!")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Where "table" (= Table), "colonne" (= Column) and "typede" (= type) are the name of three textboxes

Answer (score 0):

i am not a pro but want to try it. I have used *WithEvents* statement.

Please try following code. And i am assuming that, you are writing code in two forms right? *Form7*  and *Form 8*

In Form 7,do this

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form7
 ...
 Public Event LoadDataGridView(sender As System.Object)

Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cmd.Connection = cn
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If table.Text <> "" And colonne.Text <> "" And typede.Text <> "" Then
      --- Your stuff here. After completion of code, following event will be raised

      RaiseEvent LoadDataGridView(sender)
    Else
        MsgBox("Vous devez remplir les trois champs!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If table.Text <> "" And colonne.Text <> "" Then
      -- Your stuff here. After completion of code, following event will be raised


      RaiseEvent LoadDataGridView(sender)
    Else
        MsgBox("Vous devez remplir correctement les deux premiers champs!")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Now ,
In Form 8, do this

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form8
Private WithEvents form7 As New Form7

Private Sub Form8_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    -- You stuff
End Sub

Private Sub form7_LoadDataGridView(sender As Object) Handles form7.LoadDataGridView
 'Call load procedure to reload datagridview
 Form8_Load(Nothing,Nothing)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Miss.

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I think my problem is that my dataset isn't updated and doesn't know that I've added a new column in my database.
When I add a new column, I can see it in my database but not in my dataset.

So, do you know if I add a new column in my dataset or my datagridview, will it be added to the database too?

Comment: @Mecreance: Are you sure that 
i) the new column is added in same table "CONSULTE "  and you're retrieving data again from the same table "CONSULTE "? 
--You have added new column via Button_click event and you are retrieving from Form_load event, so, make sure table name is same on both block of code.

Comment: @Mecreance:Honestly, i don't know about adding column to dataset and then to db. But my suggestion is first add to table in db and refill dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I've found a way!